Byteman java agent: How to change the return type of a class method
Class Name: org.test.ClassName
Method Name: method1
Actual Return Type: ResponseEntity<Task>
Expected response: Task ie. {"id": "test"}

My requirement is to intercept the response and modify its response to the expected response given above. I tried to modify the return object in the return statement, but byteman is throwing an error that return type cannot be changed. How to achieve this? Tried below, but didnt work

RULE a
CLASS org.test.ClassName
METHOD method1
AT EXIT
IF true
DO
    return new Task();
ENDRULE



Other requirement is to change the actual return type's property itself ie. Response of the method is ResponseEntity<>(new Task, HttpStatus.OK), i want to change the return property to ResponseEntity<>(new Task, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN). How to achieve this? Tried below, but didnt work

RULE a
CLASS com.vmware.mangle.services.controller.TestController
METHOD getUser
AT EXIT
IF TRUE
DO
    ResponseEntity<Resource<User>> responseEntity = $!;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
    
    if (httpStatus == HttpStatus.OK) {
        ResponseEntity<Resource<User>> newResponseEntity =
            new ResponseEntity<>(responseEntity.getBody(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        $! = newResponseEntity;
    }
ENDRULE


You cannot change the return type of a method using Byteman.
However, you can change the return value of a method so long as the value you return has the same type.
The reason your rule is not working is because you are trying to use template parameters. Template parameters are valid in Java source code but not in Byetman rules. That's because the bytecode that Byteman has to transform in order to inject your rule does not include details of template parameters. They are erased by the javac compiler.
If you change your rule to omit the template parameters it should work. Here is what I suggest you try:
RULE a
CLASS com.vmware.mangle.services.controller.TestController
METHOD getUser
AT EXIT
IF TRUE
DO
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = $!;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = responseEntity.getStatusCode();

    if (httpStatus == HttpStatus.OK) {
        ResponseEntity newResponseEntity =
            new ResponseEntity(responseEntity.getBody(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        $! = newResponseEntity;
    }
ENDRULE

